# Is this kind of DB extension ok? / other faster(writing) NewRow() implementations

Tags: c#

Do you agree this extension is ok, with normal code guidelines?

Or do you prefer another easy writing NewRow() solution?

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a new row, with action. After the action, the row will be added to the tab
        /// </summary>
        public static void NewRow(this DataTable table, Action<DataRow> action)
        {
            var r = table.NewRow();
            action.Invoke(r);
            table.Rows.Add(r);
        }
....

            var tab = new DataTable();
            tab.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(string));
            tab.Columns.Add("Bar", typeof(string));

            //add one row 
            tab.NewRow((x) => x["FOO"] = "TEST");

            //add another row 
            tab.NewRow((x) =>
            {
                x["FOO"] = "TEST2";
                x["BAR"] = "TEST2";
            });
```

Comment: Well.... it doesn't compile ;-)

Comment: but i guess you would get it running, if you want ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Asking whether people agree with things is, almost by definition, entirely subjective. Will it work? Probably. To my mind, it seems entirely redundant compared with just *returning* the row and letting the caller work with it after adding, and note that anonymous methods (the lambdas) can have unexpected costs re captured variables etc. But; it'll work.

Personally, my main concern would be that you're using `DataTable` *at all*. There *are* scenarios where this is appropriate, but they are few and far between, and `DataTable` **should not** be your default data-handling choice (unless you're writing a tool that deals with ad-hoc queries on unknown databases). Contrast:

```cs
var list = new List<MyPurposeSpecificType>();
//...
list.Add(new MyPurposeSpecificType { Foo = "TEST", Bar = "TEST2" });
```